# Ember.js linkTo helper doesn't load correspondant route and displays template

Tags: ember.js, jsfiddle

While trying to setup a jsfiddle for another question that 
I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971390/ember-getting-property-from-controller-in-model) on SO I encountered the following problem:
I try to load the "amounts" route that should render the "amounts" template via the
{{linkTo}} helper in the "index" template. But when I click on the link I'm not beeing redirected to  the "amounts" template, it just stays on the "index" template and does nothing (so I guess the "amounts" route isn't loaded too).
Handlebars Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
<h1>Conversion</h1>
<label>Conversion Factor:</label>
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="conversionFactor"}}
{{#linkTo "amounts" }}Show Amounts{{/linkTo}} 
{{outlet}}
</script>
```

Router setup:

```
// Router
App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('amounts', function() {
    this.route('new')
});
});
```

This is my first time with jsfiddle, so probably I misconfigured something.
I'm sure there's a simple reason why it doesn't work, but I couln't figure it out so far.
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nairam/Ttsmk/3/).
Any hint would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, setup LOG_TRANSITIONS in your Ember.Application.create call to look like this:

```
Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true  
})
```

and check out the console. This will give you more clues about what's going on. First off, I saw that you need to define an App.Store, or calls to model.find() won't work.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({});
```

Latest version of ember-data doesn't have revision numbers anymore, but earlier versions will, so in that case, you'd have to provide a revision number.

Your amounts controller has a typo, so that it's probably also breaking the route.
    Uncaught ReferenceError: EmberArrayController is not defined

Here's an updated fiddle that makes this a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/Ttsmk/5/

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help and for having fixed it! So, from ember-data revision: 12 on we don't have to provide a revision number anymore? That means there are no breaking changes anymore until 1.0? Thanks also for the tip with LOG_Transitions. I will use that from now on.

Comment: I believe the last revision number was 13, but you don't need to add when you're using the latest ember-data. It's handled by versioning. I don't know about breaking changes, ember-data is still very much in motion.